# Query using CASE, WHEN, THEN in postgresql not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have three tables, `tbl_doctors_details`, `tbl_time` and `tbl_token`.

I have to select the details from `tbl_time` or `tbl_token`. That is if for particular doctor in hospital have `t_type` is `time` then select from `tbl_time` else select from `tbl_token`.

For example, for `doctor_id` is 100 and `hospital_id` 1, the `t_type` is `time`. So for this user, details should select from `tbl_time` table.

Below is the sample structure and data of three tables:

[image]
[image]

How can I use **CASE** condition in query here?

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
( SELECT * CASE WHEN t_type= 'time'  FROM dbname.tbl_doctors_details t1 THEN
           dbname.tbl_time t2
           ELSE
           dbname.tbl_token t2
           WHERE t1.hospital_id=t2.hospital_id AND t1.doctor_id=t2.doctor_id);
```

I know the query is not working, but how can I make the query working?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I think normalizing the database would make it far more easier for you to do that.

Comment: I have given the sample data to ask the question..It is different from the real one

Answer (score 0):

You need to join both tables using two LEFT JOINs and then COALESCE to find the matching data:

```
SELECT t1.*,
   colaesce(t_time.hospid, t_token.hospid),
   colaesce(t_time.start, t_token.start)
FROM dbname.tbl_doctors_details t1
LEFT JOIN dbname.tbl_time t_time
  ON t1.doctor_id=t_time.doctor_id
 AND t1.t_type= 'time'
LEFT JOIN dbname.tbl_token t_token
  ON t1.doctor_id=t_token.doctor_id
 AND t1.t_type= 'token';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE WHEN` in your `SELECT` and `LEFT JOIN` both tables. In both `LEFT JOIN` use the condition of `t_type` to join on the tables. In your `SELECT` you can now check whether table `t1` or `t2` was joined and select the preferred column. Here's a sample (the selected column is just a sample to illustrate):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.id IS NULL THEN t2.id ELSE t1.id END AS joined_id
FROM tbl_doctors_details as tbl_base
LEFT JOIN tbl_time t1 ON t1.t_type = 'time' AND t1.doc_id = tbl_base.doc_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_token t2 ON t2.t_type = 'token' AND t2.doc_id = tbl_base.doc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Serious smell of doing homework for someone here.. Meh

```
SELECT

  doctors.*
  , CASE
    WHEN doctors.type = 'time' THEN time.start
    ELSE token.start
  END AS start

FROM

doctors

  LEFT OUTER JOIN time
    ON time.doc_id = doctors.doc_id
    AND time.hospital_id = doctors.hospital_id
    AND doctors.t_type = 'time'

  LEFT OUTER JOIN token
    ON token.doc_id = doctors.doc_id
    AND token.hospital_id = doctors.hospital_id
    AND doctors.t_type = 'token'
```